# Use jQuery to spilt and append a hash of items in to groups of 5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can I use jQuery to spilt and append a hash of items in to groups of 5? In rails I can use: `in_groups_of()`. Does jQuery have something similar?

*Image for clarification of objective:*
[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="vehicle_model" style="display: none">
  <h3>Vehicle Model</h3>

  <table id="model" class="vehicle_options">
      <tr>
        <!-- model options -->
      </tr>
  </table>
<span id="model_selected"></span> 
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
models = {"Acura":["CL", "ILX", "ILX Hybrid", "Integra", "Legend", "MDX", "NSX", "RDX", "RL", "RLX", "RSX", "SLX", "TL", "TLX", "TSX", "TSX Sport Wagon", "Vigor", "ZDX"]};

$.each(models["Acura"], function( key, value ) {
  $('#model tr').append('<td id=\"'+value+'\">'+value+'</td>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to generate the result you wanted. I created an internal paging mechanism.

You can see it in action at http://jsfiddle.net/SyyTL/7/

The code I wrote for this demo is as below:

```
function performRender() {
    var models = {
        "Acura": ["CL", "ILX", "ILX Hybrid", "Integra", "Legend", "MDX", "NSX", "RDX", "RL", "RLX", "RSX", "SLX", "TL", "TLX", "TSX", "TSX Sport Wagon", "Vigor", "ZDX"]
    };

    var pageSize = 5;

    var pageCount = models["Acura"].length / pageSize;

    for (var page = 0; page < pageCount; page++) {
        var pageElements = models["Acura"].slice(page * pageSize, (page + 1) * pageSize);
        debugger;
        var newTr = $('<tr />');
        $.each(pageElements, function (index, value) {
            $('<td />', {
                text: value
            }).appendTo(newTr);
        });

        newTr.appendTo('#model');
    }
}

$('button').click(function(){performRender();});
```

Please mark as answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hey thanks that works but so much code for something so simple. I will accept your answer because it works. But how could this be refactored to something less bloated? Ideas?

Comment: Actually I had expanded steps to help you better understand the code. You can optimize/shrink it if you want, even your line for append operation will work there. Thanks